# Vue 3 - How to catch errors in compile/compileToFunction

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Using the vue runtime compiler, allowing users to input their own html templates to then be compiled. If the user enters some invalid code i need to handle the error gracefully, but i can not seem to catch syntax errors within a component when it's being compiled

[image: User enters invalid javascript inside the click attribute, throws a syntax error]

I am trying to catch this error in the compile function as the screenshot below

[image]

then use it as the render() function on my component...

```
{
data() {...}
render:renderFunction,
}
```

alas to no avail
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget `await` there?

Comment: @Dimava compile is not an async function, it's the function that generates the function that is used to render?